# How can I create a measure in Power BI that groups two columns and counts distinct values?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am using Power BI and need to create a measure for Failure Counts. I have a table that contains a Failure Mode column and a Date column. For each unique combination of Failure Mode and Date I want to calculate the count. I am trying to write a dax expression to accomplish this. Can anyone point out the best way to do this so I get the expected output in my attached screenshot example?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8ZsV.png)

From some extensive googling I find solutions that are close to what I am after but don't quite do it. Some of them return a table or set of columns instead of a scalar value like I am expecting.
The closest dax expression I found was this:
Failure Count =
CALCULATE (
COUNT ( 'public failure'[failureModeId] ),
FILTER ( ALL ( 'public failure' ), 'public failure'[Failure Mode] = MAX ( 'public failure'[Failure Mode] ) ),
FILTER ( ALL ( 'public failure' ), 'public failure'[Experiment Start Time] = MAX ( 'public failure'[Experiment Start Time] ) )
)

But the above expression does not do the counts correctly and I don't understand the use of the MAX function.
I would expect to do something like this:
DISTINCTCOUNT((GROUPBY('public failure', 'public failure'[Failure Mode], 'public failure'[Experiment Start Time]))
But this does not work either.

Comment: Can you give an example of the output you received vs what you expected?

Comment: I had to cheat to do this. (Maybe I should have used an iterator instead of creating a column in the table, but this seems to work...) ... ModelDate is a calculated Column. (I'm "merging" the date and the model together).

ModelDate=CONCATENATE(CONCATENATE(Table1[Date], "---"),Table1[FailureMode])

then you can just create a unique count of that column:
DISTINCTCOUNT([ModeDate])

Comment: Okay, I asked around and worked on it some more. This is what I came up with.
The trick is to concatenate the [date] and [failure mode] columns. Then you can create a calculated table and solve it. This is the table definition:

UniqueFailureAndDate = ADDCOLUMNS(
                    'Failures', 
                    "ConcatenatedColumn", 'Failures'[FailureMode] & 
                    FORMAT('Failures'[Date], "dd/mm/yyyy")
                    ) 

Then you can create a measure to do the counts with this measure:

Distinct RA = DISTINCTCOUNT('UniqueFailureAndDate'[ConcatenatedColumn])

Comment: see my recent post. thanks.

Comment: So I need to accomplish this by using measures only. Can anyone help with that?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using a measure

First filter on the Date column then filter on Failure Mode column and then count the Failure Mode column values.

```
Measure = CALCULATE(COUNT(Data[Failure Mode]), FILTER(ALL(Data), Data[Date] = SELECTEDVALUE(Data[Date])), FILTER(ALL(Data), Data[Failure Mode] = SELECTEDVALUE(Data[Failure Mode])))
```

[image]

Comment: see my recent post. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have tried all of these approaches and I am still not able to get the desired result. I have two measures:

Failure Count = COUNT('public failure'[Failure Mode])
and
Total Runs =
CALCULATE(
DISTINCTCOUNT('public failure'[experimentId]),
REMOVEFILTERS('public failureMode'[Failure Type], 'public failureMode'[Designation])
)

These are what I am using to calculate a third measure:
Failure Rate = DIVIDE([Failure Count], [Total Runs]) * 100

I want to graph this third measure but I want to set the legend to Failure Mode to see the failure rates per failure mode. When I do this the graph displays incorrect values.

This shows the table of data that displays correctly, but the failure rates are not broken out by failure mode.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wveC3.png)

Comment: Does not answer the question.